# ConcurrentModificationException on for loop

Tags: android, autocompletetextview, custom-adapter

I am using a custom adapter in combination with an AutoCompleteTextView view to populate drop down suggestions as a user types. However it is crashing and the logcat is giving me ConcurrentModificationException on the for(Object object : result) line of the code below

```
@Override
protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
   parts.clear();
   if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
      List<?> result = (List<?>) results.values;
      for (Object object : result) {
          if (object instanceof Part) {
              parts.add((Part) object);
          }
      }
   } else if (constraint == null) {
       parts.addAll(partsAll);
   }
   notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

From what I understand, ConcurrentModificationException mostly occurs when trying to remove items from a list that is being iterated over.

Here is the logcat

> 04-06 14:35:01.483 25167-25167/ryko.fstwo E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL
>   EXCEPTION: main
>                                                               Process: ryko.fstwo, PID: 25167
>                                                               java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
>                                                                   at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListIterator.next(ArrayList.java:573)
>                                                                   at ryko.fstwo.adapters.PartAutoCompleteAdapter$1.publishResults(PartAutoCompleteAdapter.java:144)
>                                                                   at android.widget.Filter$ResultsHandler.handleMessage(Filter.java:282)
>                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
>                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7231)
>                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
>                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)

The crashes seem to occur when typing then hitting backspace.

Comment: Use an `Iterator` instead of for-loop

Comment: You can't use a foreach loop like that when modifying the base list (adding, removing, or replacing an element.  You can however mutate one).

Comment: @GVillani82 could you give an example of how that would look if you get some time? I replaced with an iterator but got the same crash so I believe I am implementing it incorrectly

Comment: Can you provide you implementation?

Comment: Iterator iterator = result.iterator();
                    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                        Object object = iterator.next();
                        if (object instanceof Part) {
                            parts.add((Part) object);
                        }
                    }